# SetText show text not showing

Tags: java, android

i'm developing a little app on Android but the second line is showing an error on SetText
The imcInterpretation contains text values.

The imcVlaue is working but the imcInterpreter not! Please help

```
    package com.example.calculadorimc;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.SeekBar;
import android.widget.SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private RadioGroup rgsexo;
EditText editPeso;
EditText editAltura;
TextView imcView;
TextView imcInterpreter;
SeekBar alterarAltura;
SeekBar alterarPeso;
ImageView imagem;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    editPeso = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editPeso);
    editAltura = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editAltura);
    imcView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.imcView);
    imcInterpreter = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.imcInterpreter);
    alterarAltura = (SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.alterarAltura);
    alterarPeso = (SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.alterarPeso);
    imagem = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageBody);
    alterarAltura.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(alteraralturaListener);
    alterarPeso.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(alterarpesoListener);


}

private OnSeekBarChangeListener alteraralturaListener = new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

    @Override
    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
    boolean fromUser) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        double setAltura = (alterarAltura.getProgress()) * .01d;
        // mostra na caixa o valor novo
        editAltura.setText(String.format("%.02f", setAltura).replace(',', '.'));
    }

    @Override
    public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

    }
};
private OnSeekBarChangeListener alterarpesoListener = new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

    @Override
    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
    boolean fromUser) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // Calcula o novo valor do TIP

        int setPeso = (alterarPeso.getProgress());
        // mostra na caixa o valor novo
        editPeso.setText(String.valueOf(setPeso));
    }

    @Override
    public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

    }
};
public void calculateClickHandler(View view) {

    // make sure we handle the click of the calculator button

    if (view.getId() == R.id.botaoCalcular) {

     // get the users values from the widget references

     float peso = Float.parseFloat(editPeso.getText().toString());
     float altura = Float.parseFloat(editAltura.getText().toString());

     // calculate the bmi value

     float imcValue = calcularIMC(peso, altura);

     TextView imcInterpreter = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.imcInterpreter);

     // interpret the meaning of the bmi value
     String imcInterpretation = interpretIMC(imcValue);

     // now set the value in the result text


     imcView.setText(String.format("%.02f", imcValue).replace(',', '.'));
     imcInterpreter.SetText(imcInterpretation);

    }
   }
   // the formula to calculate the BMI index

   // check for http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Body_mass_index
   private float calcularIMC (float peso, float altura) {

    return (float) (peso / (altura * altura));
   }

   // interpret what BMI means
   private String interpretIMC(float imcValue) {           

       imagem = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageBody);

       rgsexo = (RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.rgSexo);
       int selectedId = rgsexo.getCheckedRadioButtonId();  // get the id

       switch (selectedId)   // switch on the button selected
       {
            case R.id.radioMasc:
                if (imcValue < 20) {
                    imagem.setImageResource(R.drawable.slim);
                    return "Abaixo do Peso";
                   } else if (imcValue < 24.9) {
                       imagem.setImageResource(R.drawable.normal);
                    return "Peso Normal";
                   } else if (imcValue < 29.9) {
                       imagem.setImageResource(R.drawable.fat);
                    return "Acima do Peso";
                   } else if (imcValue < 39.9) {
                       imagem.setImageResource(R.drawable.fat);
                    return "Obesidade Moderada";
                   } else {
                       imagem.setImageResource(R.drawable.fat);
                    return "Obesidade Mórbida";
                   }
            case R.id.radioFem:
                if (imcValue < 19) {
                    return "Abaixo do Peso";
                   } else if (imcValue < 23.9) {

                    return "Peso Normal";
                   } else if (imcValue < 28.9) {

                    return "Acima do Peso";
                   } else if (imcValue < 38.9) {

                    return "Obesidade Moderada";
                   } else {
                    return "Obesidade Mórbida";
                   }
       }
    return null;
   }
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

Error: The method SetText(String) is undefined fot the type TextView

Thanks for all your support :)

Comment: what is imcInterpretation ? Can you be more specific, What is the error log ?

Comment: Updated the code... It's a string!

Comment: set any random text in imInterpreter directly.. imcInterpreter.setText("any text"); check and tell me if this works fine or not

Comment: Still showing the same error! Do you preffer to see the entire code?

Comment: Show me your layout xml file ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's `imcInterpreter.setText` lowercase `s`, not `imcInterpreter.SetText`